# Setting custom title when opening VLC from command line

Tags: stream, vlc, rtmp

I start VLC from a java program to play rtmp streams. I would like to set the window title to something like "stream-1" instead of the rtmp url since it doesn't tell me anything about the content.

I'm currently using this to start the stream in VLC

```
vlc.exe -vvv "rtmp url"
```

Is there some way to set the title from command line?

Answer (score 7):

Found the answer from https://github.com/bastimeyer/livestreamer-twitch-gui/wiki/Player-configuration#videolan-client

The option I was looking for was --meta-title

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when adding to playlist, though. (also, you might want to accept your own answer)

Comment: When i set --meta-title and --one-instance (to keep it from opening another vlc instance) the title in the titlebar doesnt change from the first title. for instance if i set the --meta-title to "futurama", any stream i try to play after that, no matter if i pass a completely different meta-title, it stays as futurama in the title bar until vlc is closed and reopened with a different meta-title, which defeats the purpose of "--one-instance". :l